# Efficient Four-Way Join in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, left-join

I have two tables, **Table1** and **Table2,** that I want to join. Each table has two unique keys, lets call them **Key1** and **Key2**. What I want to do is *LEFT JOIN Table2 to Table1* where any of the keys match in any of the four possible combinations:

- Table1.Key1 = Table2.Key1
- Table1.Key1 = Table2.Key2
- Table1.Key2 = Table2.Key1
- Table1.Key2 = Table2.Key2

My question is: is there any efficient way to do this? Right now I've come up with something like this, but it takes forever to run.

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE AS
SELECT a.*,
       CASE WHEN a.Key1 = b.Key1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS match1,
       CASE WHEN a.Key1 = c.Key2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS match2,
       CASE WHEN a.Key2 = b.Key1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS match3,
       CASE WHEN a.Key2 = c.Key2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS match4
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN (Select Key1 From Table2 Where Key1 is not null) b
    on a.Key1 = b.Key1 or a.Key2 = b.Key1
LEFT JOIN (Select Key2 From Table2 Where Key2 is not null) c
    on a.Key1 = c.Key2 or a.Key2 = c.Key2
;
```

Hopeless, I know...

EDIT: Example data and desired results below:

Table 1:

```
Key1     Key2     Sales    Revenue
qwer!@   dhfgfw   455      30005
asdf#$   dfg654   221      28711
edfr2#   gg%%^f   213      31667
gthy!2   awd^&5   133      13345
rf$#22   34ffgg   655      41237
bhjk%g   w3erff   122      10066
f&*yhj   dffghj   126      11004
```

Table 2:

```
Key1     Key2 
qwer!@   {null}
{null}   dfg654
ffgww2   ppolkk
{null}   gthy!2
jjjj33   l00kjl
nmnmnm   34ffgg
awd^&5   {null}
```

Desired Result:

```
Key1     Key2     Sales    Revenue   match1    match2    match3    match4
qwer!@   dhfgfw   455      30005     1         0         0         0
asdf#$   dfg654   221      28711     0         0         0         1
edfr2#   gg%%^f   213      31667     0         0         0         0
gthy!2   awd^&5   133      13345     1         0         1         0
rf$#22   34ffgg   655      41237     0         0         0         1
bhjk%g   w3erff   122      10066     0         0         0         0
f&*yhj   dffghj   126      11004     0         0         0         0
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the data and the result you hope you achieve?

Comment: No idea if this would actually help, but I'd recommend joining to the actual tables rather than the subqueries if you have any relevant indices. The way you're doing it (I think) will make it hard to use any indices you have on those tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need the combinations of the rows and not the permutations (i.e. if `table1.key` has the same value as both `table2.key1` and `table2.key2` then only one row is returned), then this should work:

```
SELECT a.*,
       CASE WHEN a.Key1 = b.Key1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS match1,
       CASE WHEN a.Key1 = b.Key2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS match2,
       CASE WHEN a.Key2 = b.Key1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS match3,
       CASE WHEN a.Key2 = b.Key2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS match4
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b
    on a.Key1 in (b.Key1, b.key2) or a.key2 in (b.key1, b.key2);
```

---

Plugging in the supplied data, this solution does work, but it needs to be aggregated to provide the results you're seeking:

```
SELECT   a.key1,
         a.key2,
         a.sales,
         a.revenue,
         MAX (CASE WHEN a.key1 = b.key1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS match1,
         MAX (CASE WHEN a.key1 = b.key2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS match2,
         MAX (CASE WHEN a.key2 = b.key1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS match3,
         MAX (CASE WHEN a.key2 = b.key2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS match4
FROM     table1 a
         LEFT JOIN table2 b
            ON a.key1 IN (b.key1, b.key2) OR a.key2 IN (b.key1, b.key2)
GROUP BY a.key1,
         a.key2,
         a.sales,
         a.revenue;
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't say I understand why, but I tried both this approach and the one from Gordon on a sample of my data (10,000 records in Table1 and 100,000 records in Table2) and this one was faster (5:51.138 vs. 13:18.075). Any ideas on _why_ this would be faster than the other approach?

Comment: A lot is going to depend on the size of `table2` and its indexes. Gordon's solution is going to have to query `table2` four times for each row in `table1`. If it could do that efficiently, then there wouldn't be much difference in the two queries.

Answer (score 4):

`or` in join conditions can be a performance problem.  I would suggest that you use `exists` instead:

```
SELECT a.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table2 b where a.Key1 = b.Key1) then 1 else 0 end) as match1,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table2 b where a.Key1 = b.Key2) then 1 else 0 end) as match2,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table2 b where a.Key2 = b.Key1) then 1 else 0 end) as match3,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table2 b where a.Key2 = b.Key2) then 1 else 0 end) as match4
FROM Table1 a;
```

Filtering out the `NULL` doesn't really matter because `NULL` will fail the comparison anyway.

For best performance, you want indexes on `table2(key1)` and `table2(key2)`.